# Merging arrays with specific output format

Tags: php

I am currently learning how to manage and work with arrays. But I am a bit lost with combining two  arrays. Both arrays have the same number of values in it. The `array_merge( $thumbnails, $urls );` does what it says but it is not what I am looking for. How can i merge the array as shown below?

```
  $thumbnails = array( 
            array( "thumbnail" => "https://example1.png" ) ,
            array( "thumbnail" => "https://example2.png" ) ,
            array( "thumbnail" => "https://example3.png" ) ,            
  );

  $urls = array( 
            array( "url" => "http://www.example.com/1" ) ,
            array( "url" => "http://www.example.com/2" ) ,
            array( "url" => "http://www.example.com/3" ) ,          
  );
```

Current Result

```
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["thumbnail"]=> "https://example1.png"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["thumbnail"]=> "https://example2.png"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["thumbnail"]=> "https://example3.png"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url"]=> "http://www.example.com/1"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url"]=> "http://www.example.com/2"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url"]=> "http://www.example.com/3"
  }
```

Desired Result

```
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["thumbnail"]=> "https://example1.png"
    ["url"]=> "http://www.example.com/1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["thumbnail"]=> "https://example2.png"
    ["url"]=> "http://www.example.com/2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["thumbnail"]=> "https://example2.png"
    ["url"]=> "http://www.example.com/2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["thumbnail"]=> "https://example3.png"
    ["url"]=> "http://www.example.com/3"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just loop over them:

```
foreach ($thumbnails as $k => $src) {
   if (isset($urls[$k]) {
      $urls[$k]['thumbnail'] = $src;
   }
}
```

Comment: Simple yet effective!

Answer (score 0):

The function array_merge won't help you out here, because it's "Array in Array". But you can loop over them, so you have only one array-item. The following function returns an array just as you desire:

```
function array_merge_keys($a, $b) {
    $retArr = array();
    // Lets use min(countA, countB) so there will be no errors on
    // unbalanced array item counts.
    for($i = 0; $i < min(count($a), count($b)); $i++) {
        $retArr[$i] = array_merge($a[$i], $b[$i]);
    } // for end
    return $retArr;
}

$a = array(array("url" => "1.jpg"), array("url" => "2.jpg"));
$b = array(array("thumb" => "1.thumb.jpg"), array("thumb" => "2.thumb.jpg"));

print_r(array_merge_keys($a, $b));
```

This gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => 1.jpg
            [thumb] => 1.thumb.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => 2.jpg
            [thumb] => 2.thumb.jpg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$thumbnails = array(
            array( "thumbnail" => "https://example1.png" ) ,
            array( "thumbnail" => "https://example2.png" ) ,
            array( "thumbnail" => "https://example3.png" ) ,
  );

  $urls = array(
            array( "url" => "http://www.example.com/1" ) ,
            array( "url" => "http://www.example.com/2" ) ,
            array( "url" => "http://www.example.com/3" ) ,
  );
$thumbnails = array_combine(array_map(function($key){return 'key'.$key;},array_keys($thumbnails)),$thumbnails);
$urls = array_combine(array_map(function($key){return 'key'.$key;},array_keys($urls)),$urls);
var_dump(array_values(array_merge_recursive($thumbnails,$urls)));
```

do you mean this ?